# Views Data Export: Multiple Columns with Unique Rows (D7)

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I'm using Drupal 7

I have a view displaying users that are referenced by another entity that has a date field, like this:

**John Doe      5/6/12

John Doe      5/8/12

John Doe      5/16/12

Mary Jane     5/5/12

Mary Jane     5/7/12**

So, behind the scenes, there's a content type of "Reservation" with a date field and a user reference field.  I'm pulling in all of these reservations and displaying the user name alongside the dates of their reservations.

When I use the views_data_export module, I'm able to export this data as an xls file, which allows this data to open nicely in MS Excel.

The solution I'm looking for is to be able to group this data by user, to create unique rows with multiple columns, like this:

**John Doe      5/6/12   5/8/12   5/16/12

Mary Jane     5/5/12   5/7/12**

So, if a user has 20 pieces of data, then 20 columns will display next to that user with each column displaying each piece of data.

Comment: Hi Carson. Welcome to drupal.stackexchange!  Could you include the version of Drupal you're using in your question via tag or title?

Comment: Hi Carsonw, have you solved this? If so, how? Can you please inform us... I am overall in same situation

Comment: No, I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you noticed the following setting on the field which has multiple values:

[image]

That should be a collapsed section right under where you specify the label, etc of your field.  Just make sure you check that you want them to appear in the same row and select a separator (comma by default).

That should be all you need!  Does it transfer well for the export?

Comment: Boriana, thank you very much for your answer.  However, it doesn't fit my situation, and I updated my question above to better reflect what I'm dealing with.  I'm not dealing with a content type with one field with multiple values.  Thanks again.